# overriding site !important for a 3rd party popup

Tags: css

I want to show a popup with content in random websites.
The popup is a div I create and the content is coming from an editor with its own CSS.

Since I dont want the site CSS to effect the look of the popup I have some css to reset general things like table width inside the div that runs before the div content css.

The problem is what to do when the site uses !important on some general css like table width. I know I can add !important to the reset css so table width will reset inside the div but the content includes html/css I take from the editor which doesnt include !important. so adding !important to reset the site CSS will kill also the content CSS.

Any solution to this dreadful situation?

Comment: You should place your overlay inside of an `<iframe>`, like this you don't interrupt the parent page and can not be affected the other way around.

Comment: I prefer not to use iframe if possible. the content is responsive and need to work on mobile.